# Отслеживание обновлений страницы на PHP

Tags: php

Как можно отследить каждое обновление страницы, используя только PHP?

Задача стоит такая: есть файл, в котором есть число, олицетворяющее количество обновлений страницы.

Пробовал сделать так, но работает только для 1-го обновления - последующие он не ловит.

```
$pageWasRefreshed = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL']) && $_SERVER['HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL'] === 'max-age=0';
STATIC $numberOfUpdates = 0;
if($pageWasRefreshed) {
    file_put_contents('Files\\count.txt', ++$numberOfUpdates);
    echo $numberOfUpdates;
}
```

Comment: Вы сначала берите значение из файла, а уж потом к нему прибавляйте 1 и кладите обратно в файл. `static` тут не поможет и не нужен. Запросы то разные.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов, помогло, спасибо.